# Why the following test is always faster for the first case?

Tags: java

I was testing the performance of two different approaches to handling streams of integers (primitives). 
To my surprise, the first test case is always slower, no matter the order.

```
public void intStreamTest() {
    final int[] ints = new int[1000];
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
        ints[x] = new Random().nextInt(1000);
    }
    // T1
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++) {
        List<Integer> result =
            IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    System.out.println("T1 " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    // T2
    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++) {
        List<Integer> result =
            IntStream.of(ints).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    System.out.println("T2 " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start2));
}
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
T1 150
T2 95
```

When I change the order of test cases (swap sections T2 and T1) I get:

```
T2 153
T1 92
```

Did I make a mistake? How is it possible that a second test case is always faster (approx by 60%)?

Comment: Usually this is due to JIT compilation. There are lots of "gotchas" with microbenchmarking like this. I suggest you look into Caliper: https://github.com/google/caliper

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to read more about it, especially. Caliper looks very promising. I also added the warm-up phase for each case and indeed it has affected test output. Unfortunately, I have now a feeling that every benchmark I have ever done could be wrong.